# Can I use a metal spoon on aluminium pans?

Tags: pan, aluminum-cookware

I used a stainless steel spoon on a brand new aluminium pan (Agnelli pan), and I created some scratches (those darker lines in the attached picture). Are those scratches going to affect the safety or the functionality of the pan? Am I supposed to use only wooden or plastic spatulas to avoid them?
[image: aluminium pans]

Comment: no it will not affect the safety (an oxide will form immediately, same as the rest of the pan) or effectiveness (they're probably micro/nanometers thick).
I would however only use wood/plastic (I like bamboo)

Answer (score 2):

On an aluminium pan, no, it's fine. It's only teflon, AFAIK, that is dangerous.

*However*, sticking to something like wooden spatulas will be better for your pan and make it last longer.